# upload image from html form and display it in your website?

Tags: php, html, image, forms, upload

i have this form

```
<form action="up.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr><td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Price</td><td><input type="text" name="price" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Kilometers</td><td><input type="text" name="km" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>CC</td><td><input type="text" name="cc" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>HP</td><td><input type="text" name="hp" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Color</td><td><input type="text" name="color" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Fuel</td><td><input type="text" name="fuel" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Doors</td><td><input type="text" name="doors" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Phone</td><td><input type="text" name="tel" /></td></tr>
<input type="hidden" name="max_size" value="1000000" />
<tr><td>Image 1</td><td><input name="img1" type="file" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and when i click submit i want to display all the data above to the up.php file which contain this code so far

```
<body>
<div id="all">
<?php

$ttitle=$_POST['title'];
$pric=$_POST['price'];
$klm=$_POST['km'];
$ccc=$_POST['cc'];
$hpp=$_POST['hp'];
$colorr=$_POST['color'];
$fuell=$_POST['fuel'];
$dors=$_POST['doors'];
$thl=$_POST['tel'];
?>
<div id="cont">
<table>
<?php
echo '<tr><h1>' . $ttitle . '</h1></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Τιμή:</td><td>' . $pric . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Χιλιόμετρα:</td><td>' . $klm . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Κυβικά:</td><td>' . $ccc . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Ιπποδύναμη:</td><td>' . $hpp . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Χρώμα:</td><td>' . $colorr . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Καύσιμο:</td><td>' . $fuell . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Πόρτες:</td><td>' . $dors . '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Τηλέφωνο:</td><td>' . $thl . '</td></tr>';
?>
</table>
</div>
<div id="pics">
<?php

echo "<img src='" . $img1 . "' alt='image'/>";

?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

i've searched for many tutorials but i cannot make it work, so i really need your help to make this work..

when i click the submit button, i get this.

[image]

can you please help me? thank you in advance.

Comment: line 38 is 
echo "<img src='" . $img1 . "' alt='image'/>";

Comment: You haven't defined `$img1` in your PHP handler.

Comment: Try to add `$img1=$_POST['img1'];` underneath `$thl=$_POST['tel'];` See what that does for you, while in conjunction using `Marc B's` answer below.

Answer (score 3):

This is incorrect:

```
echo "<img src='" . $img1 . "' alt='image'/>";
                    ^^^^^
```

You have not defined $img1 anywhere, hence your error. This is also **NOT** how file uploads are performed in PHP. Given

```
<tr><td>Image 1</td><td><input name="img1" type="file" /></td></tr>
```

you will get file upload metadata in `$_FILES['img1']`. There will be no `$_POST['img1']`, period. How to handle file uploads in PHP is documented here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: That's what I was about to say, but I'll make it a comment anyway.

Comment: i tried this method with the $_FILES, i also read the tutorial in W3SCHOOLS and i cant make it work and i cannot find the reason.. is there the problem that im working local with xampp?

Comment: no way to tell. you need to do debugging yourself, e.g. check `$_FILES['img1']['error']` and compare to the codes in the docs I linked to. And FYI: w3schools is a pretty much utterly useless site. their code is bad, outdated, and frequently wrong.

Comment: @user1300556 You're not `moving` (move_uploaded_file) your uploaded file/image anywhere. I don't see any uploading functions, or did you leave that out? Of course it's going to work `locally` I presume. Can you **update/edit** your question if you have in fact, implemented an uploading function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                        $image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                        $image_type = $_FILES['image']['type']; 
                        $image_size = $_FILES['image']['size']; 
                        $image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 

                        move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "uploads/$image_name");
                        echo "<img src='uploads/$image_name' width='220' height='150'>"; 
                } ?>
```

Hey Brother! Just Try This code and everything works fine...